# How to get path to special system directories using Java

Tags: java, filesystems

How to extract the path "c:/documents and settings/user" using Java... Is there any method??

Comment: Are you asking if Java has built in ways to provide you with "Special" directories/files like a user's home directory, or settings location in Windows?

Comment: Yeah, i am expecting the same.

Comment: Regarding your question about the class location, I am not sure: see http://mindprod.com/jgloss/properties.html for all System properties. Remember that, if what you are looking for is not there, you still can pass the information as a custom property (`-DmyProperty=xxx`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

should be enough. See [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/UserHomeExample.shtml) for an example.

```
public class UserHomeExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("User Home Path: "+ System.getProperty("user.home"));
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
C:\convert\rajesh\completed>javac UserHomeExample.java

C:\convert\rajesh\completed>java UserHomeExample
User Home Path: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator
```

Comment: VonC  Can we also get current file path (i.e) from the above example can i get the info where UserHomeExamble.class is stored ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136891/getting-absolute-path-of-a-file-loaded-via-classpath, and pass in the class file name you're looking for.  If that doesn't help, ask in another question.

Answer (score 3):

The user's home directory is exposed by the JVM as a System property. You can retrieve it (as a String) using this method:

```
String homeDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

If you want the parent directory for all users (as you indicate in the question), just append `/..` to this.