# Getting absolute path of a file loaded via classpath

Tags: java

I have this very specific need wherein a file is loaded from classpath and the same is used in another module which needs it's absolute path. What are the possible ways an absolute path of a file loaded via classpath can be deduced ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `ClassLoader.getResource()` instead of `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` to get a URL. It will be, by definition, always absolute.

You can then use `openConnection()` on the URL to load the content. I'm often using this code:

```
public ... loadResource(String resource) {
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resource);
    if (url == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find " + resource + " on classpath);
    }

    log.debug("Loading {}", url); // Will print a file: or jar:file: URL with absolute path
    try(InputStream in = resource.openConnection()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though for most of java developers this answer is obvious for some it's not that obvious which class the method ```getResource()``` is, should consider adding it or pointing to the javadoc, and as it's stated in this comment if you use getResource() from class or classloader it may behave differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593154/get-a-resource-using-getresource#comment2601113_2593175

Comment: needs a better example

Answer (score 35):

use

`classLoader.getResource("/path/in/classpath").getFile();`

**See Also**

- [API Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Can you explain more instead of giving a link  because its not working 'classLoader.getResource("/path/in/classpath").getFile();'

Comment: link is still valid and alive. however I updated to latest stable version https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: You need: `SomeClassOfYours.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource`